# How can i add a delegate on gnosis safe?

Tags: python, signature, gnosis-safe, sha3

The code on the website here is not working for me:
https://safe-docs.dev.gnosisdev.com/safe/docs/tutorial_tx_service_set_delegate/

I'm trying like this:

```
import requests
import time
import sha3

SAFE_ADDRESS = '*'
OWNER_PRIVATE_KEY = '*'
DELEGATE_ADDRESS = '*'
TX_SERVICE_BASE_URL = 'https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io'

totp = int(time.time()) // 3600
hash_to_sign = sha3.keccak_256(text=DELEGATE_ADDRESS + str(totp))
account = Account.from_key(OWNER_PRIVATE_KEY)
signature = account.signHash(hash_to_sign)

add_payload = {
    "safe": SAFE_ADDRESS,
    "delegate": DELEGATE_ADDRESS,
    "signature": signature.signature.hex(),
    "label": "My new delegate2"
}

print(list_response.text)
print(list_response.status_code)
```

i get this error:

```
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    hash_to_sign = sha3.keccak_256(text=DELEGATE_ADDRESS + str(totp))
TypeError: 'text' is an invalid keyword argument for sha3_224()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, the keccack method in the sha3 library does not accept the kwarg `text`.

The [tutorial](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-docs/blob/devportal/docs/tutorial_tx_service_set_delegate.md) (better link) states that you need to import `eth_account`. This in turn imports `eth_utils`, which does some data massaging to proxy into the underlying sha3 library (which may or may not be the one you've imported)

So the short answer is to replace `sha3` with `eth_account`, and use `eth_account.keccak(text=...)` for your `hash_to_sign` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I got to work was the safe-cli

https://github.com/5afe/safe-cli